# file_get_contents() suddenly not working

Tags: php, file-get-contents

This is all of my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
Playlist to Scrape: <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Playlist URL">
<input type="submit">
</form>


<?php

if(isset($_GET['url'])){

        $source = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
        $regex = '/<a href="(.*?)" class="gothere pl-button" title="/';

        preg_match_all($regex,$source,$output);
        echo "<textarea cols=100 rows=50>";
        $fullUrl = array();
        foreach($output[1] as $url){
                array_push($fullUrl,"http://soundcloud.com".$url);
        }
        $final = implode(";",$fullUrl);
        echo $final;
        echo "</textarea>";
}else{
        echo "borks";
}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Yesterday, it worked fine.
What the code *should* do is:
Take a Soundcloud URL, extract the individual songs, and then print them like song1;song2;song3

Again, this worked fine yesterday, and I haven't changed anything since, I think...

I have tried to comment the other code out, and just keeping $source = file_get_contents($_GET['url']); and echoing $source, but it returned blank, which makes me think it is a problem with file_get_contents.

If you have any idea on why this is happening, I would appreciate hearing it.  Thanks!

Comment: Is $_GET['url'] valid and getting what it should?

Comment: You think you haven't changed anything?!

Comment: Yes, I have done echo $_GET['url'] and it has printed the URL that I input.

Comment: 1. you should probably use the SoundCloud API. 2. You should probably enable error reporting. try `var_dump($source)` is it `(bool) false`?

Comment: @jeroen yes, I tested it before I went to bed, and I'm not sure if I might have accidentally done something to it before I went to bed that caused it to break.

Comment: var_dump($source) returns bool(false), and I didn't know about the SoundCloud API, ill look into it, though I'm not sure if it would be able to do what I need

Comment: Then `error_reporting(E_ALL);` `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, what is the result of your code execution now?

Comment: I get Warning: file_get_contents(http://soundcloud.com/em202020/sets/good): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request.  Think I found the problem...

Comment: @jeroen That happened exactly in our case. The root cause was a different certificate on the server that `file_get_contents` is trying to read from. We had to change our `file_get_contents` `context`/`options` to accommodate for that. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

What might have happened is that a new SSL certificate was installed on the server that `file_get_contents` is trying to access. In our case, the target server had a new SSL certificate installed on its domain from another vendor and another wild-card domain.

Changing our config a little bit fixed the problem.

```
 $opts = array(
   'http' => array(
     'method' => "GET",
     'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n".
                 "Accept: application/json\r\n",
     'ignore_errors' => true
   ),
   // VVVVV   The extra config that fixed it
   'ssl' => array(
     'verify_peer' => false,
     'verify_peer_name' => false,
   )
   // ^^^^^
 );
 $context = stream_context_create($opts);
 $result = file_get_contents(THE_URL_WITH_A_CHANGED_CERTIFICATE, false, $context);
```

I found this solution thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37787877/1385429). It even was downvoted.

This certainly explained the fact that `file_get_contents` **suddenly** stops working.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't have enough information for someone to help you.

To start with though, I would

- Check that the script is receiving the URL get parameter correctly (`var_dump($_GET['url'])`)
- Check what PHP fetches from the URL (`var_dump(file_get_contents($_GET['url']))`;

My guess is either your server admin turned off FOPEN URL wrappers, or the owner of the site you're scraping decided they didn't want you scraping their site, and are blocking requests from your PHP scripts.

It also helps to turn error reporting all the way up, and set display errors to 1

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Although if you've been developing without this, chances are there's lots of working-but-warning-worthy code in your application.

Good luck.

Comment: Ive added the error reporting, and they print some errors.  Ill see what I can do with them, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (I was also frequently downloading one page but not soundcloud) it was because of F5 “bobcmn” Javascript detection at server.

When I wrote into my php script somethinkg like `var_dump($source);` - to see what server sent - then I saw that response starts with this code: `window[“bobcmn”] = ...`

More here:
https://blog.dotnetframework.org/2017/10/10/understanding-f5-bobcmn-javascript-detection/