# file_get_contents( ) not working

Tags: php, apache, curl

I have a script that uses `file_get_contents()` to get json response from remote server .
while `file_get_contents()` is working properly on local files but not working with http or https it gives me the following error `file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in` and `file_get_contents(https://api.domain.com/resolve.json?url=blablabla): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found` .. it is a dedicated server and I have WHM .. I've tried

1. setting `allow_url_fopen = on` on WHM PHP configuration Editor but This didn't work.
2. creating a php.ini file with `allow_url_fopen = on` in the directory where the error occurred but this didn't work.
3. added `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 'On');` to the start of the PHP script but this didn't work .

I know I can use Curl instead but I want to know why this is not working .. the script is working properly on other server and localhost

**update :**

```
phpinfo();
```

gives me

```
allow_url_fopen Off 
allow_url_include   Off 
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off
```

that means my php.ini changes didn't take effect .. what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is probably being overridden so that you cannot turn it on. Even with your php.ini, etc., run a `phpinfo()` and see if it's actually being changed. My advice is to use curl, fwiw.

Comment: edit `php.ini` in `/etc/`, after restart webserver `service httpd restart`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Login to your server via ssh and type

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini //<<<< ubuntu/debian server, might differ for you
```

in the file, simply press `"ctrl + w"` and type `"allow_url_fopen"` and Return, most probably you will come to the explanation first, so repeat the search a couple of times. Now you can change the entry from

`allow_url_fopen=0`

to

`allow_url_fopen=1`

press `"ctrl + x"` and confirm the file save with `"y"`.

Then type

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This will restart apache so the new php.ini configuration can be loaded. After those steps, you should be able to use `file_get_contents` externally.

---

SIDENOTE

If you can't find your php.ini file, you will find the path to the loaded php.ini file in the top section of your `phpinfo()`

[image]

Comment: Thank you .. I forgot to check loaded configuration file .. that made the trick .. I had an old php.ini public_html folder .. but shouldn't the file in subfolder overwrite it ?

Comment: The files where in the subdirectory where I put the new php.ini

Comment: Hm, I think the configuration file that is primary loaded will always be in above mentioned location.

Comment: in new version php8, allow_url_fopen = On, patch cpanel/ea-php80/root/etc/php.ini

Answer (score 27):

```
$url= 'https://example.com';

$arrContextOptions=array(
      "ssl"=>array(
            "verify_peer"=>false,
            "verify_peer_name"=>false,
        ),
    );  

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

This will allow you to get the content from the url whether it is a HTTPS, no need to change in php ini.

Comment: Thanks. This extra config is exactly what fixed our problem. I wrote an answer here at another question (that focusses un the _suddenness_ of the problem). I referenced your answer as my source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48305167/1385429

Comment: not agree, MPDF use file_get_contents and many other libraries too, are you crazy to recommend change as this their core code??

Answer (score 8):

Use curl as an alternative of file_get_contents( ) and this is the function I am using

```
function url_get_contents ($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have root access, edit `php.ini`, usually located at `/etc/php.ini`.

If you dont have root access, try to add `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 'On');` or `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', '1');`.

If you can't see `php.ini`, try using `phpinfo()` in a PHP script to find the `php.ini` location.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = $_GET['id'] ;
$api_url = "http://localhost/../API.php?id='$id' ";
$port = 80;
$ch = curl_init( );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
// Allowing cUrl funtions 20 second to execute
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5 );
// Waiting 20 seconds while trying to connect
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5 );                                 
$response_string = curl_exec( $ch );

echo $response_string;
```

**This is the best way to solve the web request problems**

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers, it might be possible that SELinux settings might not allow you to connect from httpd. For this you can refer to this link
https://drib.tech/programming/php-file_get_contents-not-working

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This work perfect:

```
function get_site($url) { 
  $file = fopen($url, 'r');
  if(!$file) return;
  $buffer='';
  while(!feof($file))   {
    $buffer .= fgets($file, 4096);
    }
  fclose($file);
  return $buffer;
}
```