# Instagram RSS Feed in PHP script

Tags: php, rss, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to create an RSS feed by following [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/jonathanbell/48c46d9fc2913fba3292) but currently there are no results.

Here's my RSS:

> http://imodelicon.com/test/instagram/instarss.php?hashtag=carshow

My http host is `http://imodelicon.com` and Request URI is `/test/instagram/instrass.php`. Is it correct?

If so, I don't see the hashtag result after the link. Could anyone help if there are other issues?

Comment: This link works http://demos.jonathanbell.ca/instarss/instarss.php?hashtag=carshow There is something in your code. Unfortunately we are not familiar with your code hence you will have to debug it manually.

Comment: Thank you, vbrmnd. You are right. The link is working. I copy the same script but it is not working in my end. Is it too much to ask you listing out the major points in this script when I double check it again?

Comment: I check entire code which needs to add "http host" and "request URI" portion to make script works. Are there other codes I need to edit?

Comment: @sky are u using the right version oh php for it?

Comment: I think so. It is php 5.5

Comment: I tried it locally and its working. Only thing that comes to my mind is your settings. Check what file_get_contents is returning. It might be blocked by a firewall or your hosting provider. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613432/file-get-contents-not-working

Comment: You know, Vbrmnd. After I double check file_get content from server, you are right!! Now, it is working beautifully!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! You really make my day!!

Comment: How can i give you a star or close question..?

Comment: Thanks @Sky. Glad I could help. Not sure though how to close the question.

Comment: @vbrmnd you can add your suggestion as an answer, not as a comment and Sky can accept it afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @YakovL, adding as answer.

I tried to deploy your app locally and its working fine.

Since it is not working at your end, the only thing that comes to my mind is your settings.
Check what file_get_contents is returning. It might be blocked by a firewall or your hosting provider.

Also, check [file_get_contents() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613432/file-get-contents-not-working) for additional pointers.

Comment: Thank you, Vbrmnd!

Comment: https://browse-tutorials.com/snippet/php-instagram-rss-feed this one leverages paging. Thus enables you to control the items count.